# How to detect area of change between two images in openCV?

Tags: java, opencv, image-processing

I am using [HOG (Histogram of Oriented Gradients)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Histogram_of_oriented_gradients) features to detect the similarity between two images, and find out which part of image has changed. The testing scenario is that I first take a picture of a table as a reference, and then I add an object on the table and take the picture again at the same position.

Then I resize and compute the HOG feature array on both pictures:

```java
Imgproc.resize(mGray, mGray, new Size(128,256));
hog.compute(mGray, des);
```

Then I compute the distance:

```java
double distance=0;
for (int i = 0; i < ref.length; i++) {
    distance += Math.abs( ref[i] - a[i]);
}
if (distance < Threshold) {
    Log.i(TAG,"has difference    " + distance);
} else {
    Log.i(TAG,"has no  difference    " + distance);
}
```

Now I can detect there are changes on the two pictures, but then how can I quickly determine where is the change? Initially, I am thinking of splitting the pictures into many small blocks and computing the HOG feature values for these small blocks and comparing the distance block by block, but that has poor efficiency.

If there is a better way to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hog descriptors only tell you that there is a change but not the place where the changes are. You can use sift features and descriptors and determine what all features that matched and draw a bounding box that includes all the matching features.

Instead of block by block on the descriptors itself you can use k-means cluster and then do a block by block comparison on the cluster numbers.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why SIFT helps?